# Data corruption in Kinesis Producer

Tags: encoding, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I'm using kinesis producer to insert some analytics data in AWS Cloudwatch. 
This is the entire flow of the data : 
1. Kinesis producer (Using java SDK) -> Kinesis Stream -> AWS lambda function -> AWS Cloudwatch

Producer version used in Kinesis :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>amazon-kinesis-producer</artifactId>
    <version>0.13.1</version>
</dependency>
```

After pushing the my analytics data to the producer with the following code,

```
kinesisProducer.addUserRecord(stream, "101", ByteBuffer.wrap(requestString.getBytes()));
```

Data being sent to the producer:

```
{
    "version": null,
    "namespace": "namespace",
    "metricdata": [
        {
            "name": "system",
            "unit": "Megabytes",
            "value": 879,
            "timestamp": 1590233414481,
            "dimensions": [
                {
                    "name": "systemName",
                    "value": "ramTotal"
                }
            ],
            "type": "gauge"
        }]
}
```

I came to know that, the data is converted into base64 format by kinesis producer. Hence
data being received in the lambda function after decoding like this -

```
const payload = Buffer.from(record.kinesis.data, 'base64').toString('ascii');
```

payload is coming like this

```
s   B
101fGaG
{
    "version": null,
    "namespace": "`$\u0017`$>`$0o?=o?=`$!`$\u0010`$*",
    "metricdata": [
        {
            "name": "system",
            "unit": "Megabytes",
            "value": 879,
            "timestamp": 1590233414481,
            "dimensions": [
                {
                    "name": "systemName",
                    "value": "ramTotal"
                }
            ],
            "type": "gauge"
        }]
}
```

Can anyone help me out with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kinesis Producer aggregates small records into larger records upto 1MB. Kinesis consumer has to deaggregate the records before processing.

[reference link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/kinesis-record-deaggregation.html)

[de-aggregation library](https://github.com/awslabs/kinesis-aggregation)